# How to get text with its processing?

Tags: python

I'm new to python I have json file containting tweets with json format . I need to get text with some processing on it like small not capital letters and so on . I have the script that make processing on text . I used this command first to get text only

Comment: is your **json** file called `tweets.txt`? Why not `.json`?

Comment: well I know it works, the extension has no effect on the actual handling of the file, just indicates how it **should** be handled.

Comment: could you save me (and other people who could help you) the time of looking it up and explain specifically what `jq -r .text` does?

Comment: well you can techincally do something with `subprocess.call("jq -r .text", ...)` but I'd want to suggest a python only way of doing the whole processing since it'd be less error prone then using subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent for

```
cat tweets.txt | jq -r .text > text.txt
```

in python is

```
import json

open("text.txt", "w").write(json.load(open("tweets.txt", "r"))["text"])
```